# Static polymorphism: How to define the interface?

Tags: c++, templates, static-polymorphism

Below is a very simple example of what I understand as static polymorphism. The reason why I'm not using dynamic polymorphism is that I do not want to obstruct inlining of functions of `PROCESSOR` in `op`.

```
template <class PROCESSOR>
void op(PROCESSOR* proc){
    proc->doSomething(5);
    proc->doSomethingElse();
}

int main() {
    ProcessorY py;
    op<ProcessorY>(&py);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this example is: There exists no explicit definition of what functions a `PROCESSOR` has to define. If one is missing, you will just get a compile error. I think this is bad style.

It also has a very practical drawback: On-line assistance of IDEs cannot of course show you the functions that are available on that object.

What is a good/official way to define the public interface of a `PROCESSOR`?

Comment: First of all, why do you take pointers? Secondly, the definition is given by you, in a documentation of that function template.

Comment: Also, IDEs not showing you a list of member is not a very significant drawback.

Comment: You'll just have to wait for [Concepts TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Comment: @Columbo: Pointers because I do not want to pass the potentially huge PROCESSOR by value. And I personally like the IDE's suggestions, so it's a matter of taste whether that drawback is significant or not...

Comment: Why pointers instead of references?

Comment: @Columbo: What would be the difference of references regarding the question?

Comment: @Columbo I assume because of the reasons described in [this convention](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html?showone=Reference_Arguments#Reference_Arguments), which I support.

Comment: @Michael None. And I haven't implied that it makes one, either. I was just surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there is no problem with your static polymorphism example. Since it's static, i.e. compile-time resolved, by definition it has less strict demands regarding its interface definition.

Also it's absolutely legitimate that the incorrect code just won't compile/link, though a more clear error message from the compiler would be nicer.

If you, however, insist on interface definition, you may rewrite your example the following way:

```
template <class Type>
class Processor
{
public:
    void doSomething(int);
    void doSomethingElse();
};

template <class Type>
void op(Processor<Type>* proc){
    proc->doSomething(5);
    proc->doSomethingElse();
}

// specialization
template <>
class Processor<Type_Y>
{
    // implement the specialized methods
};

typedef Processor<Type_Y> ProcessorY;

int main() {
    ProcessorY py;
    op(&py);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Puppy Please elaborate on how this would improve the answer.

Comment: I think @valdo gave a good answer on a possible solution to tackle this problem. But I would also be interested in the CRTP idea.

Comment: The proposed `Processor<T>` solution is terrible. It severely reduces the ability of `op()` to be generic while providing zero benefits. Your `Processor<Type_Y>` specialization could just as easily not implement any of those functions and then you're in exactly the same place you started from.

Answer (score 3):

> There exists no explicit definition of what methods a PROCESSOR has to define. If one is missing, you will just get a compile error. I think, this is bad style.

It is. It is not. It may be. It depends.

Yes, if you want to define behavior in this way, you may want to also restrict the content, that template parameters should have. Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this "explicitly" right now.

What you want is [constraints and concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) feature, that was supposed to appear as part of C++ 11, but was delayed and is still not available as of C++ 14.

However, getting compile-time error is often the best way to restrict template parameters. As an example, we can use `std` library:

**1) Iterators.**

C++ library [defines](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/) few types of iterators: `forward_iterator`, `random_access_iterator` and others. For each type, there is a set of properties and valid expressions defined, that are guaranteed to be available. If you used iterator, that is not fully compatible with `random_access_iterator` in container, that requires `random_access_iterator`, you will get compiler error at some point (most likely, when using dereference operator ([]), which is required in this iterator class).

**2) Allocators.**

All containers in `std` library use allocator to perform memory allocation/deallocation and objects construction. By default, [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) is used. If you want to exchange it with your own, you need to ensure, that it has everything, that `std::allocator` is guaranteed to have. Otherwise, you will get compile-time error.

So, until we get concepts, this is the best and most widely used solution.

Comment: Concept checks can be easily emulated by instantiating expected member function pointers of the checked class.